# Fast way to copy rows from one table into another

Tags: sql-server

Table A is a normal table in tempdb. Table B is a local temp table. What is the fastest way to copy a set of rows that match some condition from A to B. Table B is empty, initially.

Something faster than:

```
insert into #TableB
select * from TableA
```

Comment: Did you get your table names the wrong way round in your question? Either way, I shouldn't think there'll be a quicker way than that; you're asking the database at the lowest level.

Comment: @Neil Barnwell You could add the `SET INSERT_REALLY_FAST ON` directive (may not be a real directive).

Comment: In the first place you should not be doing inserts without specifying the columns. There is a slight performance hit for not specifying and of course the code is more fragile and will break more easily if you do not specify.

Comment: "Table A is a normal table in tempdb." Just curious as to why you'd be creating "normal" tables in tempdb?

Comment: indexes might speed up the process basing them on your conditions

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT *
INTO MyNewTable
FROM MyTable
```

or backup a table and restore it manually.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything faster than a directive to

- copy matched records from a -> b
  (without additional fluff
  instructions, this is as concise as
  it gets)

>

```
insert into #TableB   -- this is the 'local (session) temp table' ?
select *
from tempdb..TableA    -- this is the 'normal table in tempdb' ?
where <condition>
```